# SVAR estimation using vars package: scoring algorithm error

Tags: r, economics

I am trying to estimate an A/B SVAR model using the scoring algorithm from the vars-package, but I get the following error:

> mA = matrix(data = c(1,0,0, 0,1, -avg_elas ,-IVoutput[2,1] , -IVoutput[3,1], 1),
>               nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
>
> mB = matrix(data = c(NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
>
> svar = SVAR(BPvar, estmethod = c('scoring'), Amat = mA, Bmat = mB , max.iter = 1000,)
>
> > Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, pos[i], i, value = 1) : subscript out of bounds
> >     In addition: Warning message:
> >     In grid.Call(C_getGPar) : reached elapsed time limit

It seems like a pretty simple error, but I can't figure out what it is related to. When I instead use estmethod = 'direct' i don't get an error but I would prefer to use the scoring method as I am trying to replicate a study.